# Where is the Web Analytics Service in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, web-analytics

I can't find Web Analytics service. It isn't in Services on Server.

In Site Actions there is "
Site Collection Web Analytics reports, 
Site Web Analytics reports " 
And it keeps saying

> "A web analytics report is not available for this site. Usage
>   processing may be disabled on this server or the usage data for this
>   site has not been processed yet. "

But I can't find it in Services on Server. 
Where is it?

Answer (score 3):

The Web Analytics report takes sometime to build as the usage data propagates itself after the service is enabled and configured.

In 2013, this does not show in the manage services on server page in central admin unlike SharePoint 2010. Additionally, check your timer jobs section for the timer job "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Import" is enabled.

Thirdly, go to your CA Usage logging page and validate that  `http://your2013centraladmin:portno/_admin/LogUsage.aspx`

Enable usage data collection is checked.

Comment: "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Import" is enabled and the usage data collection is also enabled in LogUsage.

Comment: Then wait for a day atleast to let the data populate if the site you are monitoring is actively used by users.

Comment: I had the same issue in SharePoint 2010. The data does not become available instantly.

Answer (score 1):

Techincally, SharePoint 2013 has web analytics reports...but they're a trimmed-down version of the reports available in SP 2010.  Here's the location of the reports:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chandru/archive/2013/08/31/sharepoint-2013-web-analytics-report-where-is-it.aspx

We use Angelfish Software for web analytics with our SP 2013 intranet.

Comment: But can you trust a company that sells their product for SharePoint On Premise?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Both SharePoint and Angelfish are installed on premises in our environment. We own all our data.

Comment: I believe my comments was just picking on their use of term "On Premise" in their sales material.

Comment: Ha!  I missed that entirely.  And you're right!

"Self-hosted" is the new descriptor of choice.